# Define an "extends string" type that doesn't allow union of strings

Tags: typescript, types, union-types

I have this function

```
function something<T extends string>(): void {
  // ...
}
```

I would like to restrict `T` to be a SINGLE string, and not a union of strings:

```
something<'stringOne'>(); // I want this to be allowed
something<'stringOne' | 'stringTwo'>(); // I DON'T want this to be allowed
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nr5y0w) meet your needs?  Test it out on your use cases and let me know.

Comment: @jcalz This is super clever - my initial response to this question was 'that's not possible'. I'm trying to get my head around how this works - its relying on the fact that conditional types operate on unions distributively, then comparing that back with the original type - if its a union type the original type won't be assignable to its individual parts on their own, so it errors, but its not a union type you don't have this problem. Am I interpreting that correctly?

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea.  Still waiting to see if this is what OP wants or if some unmet need makes it unworkable.

Comment: @jcalz this seems to do exactly what I need, and I understand clearly the "human readable" explanation by Ben Wainright on how it works. But I don't understand how such human readable explanation is implemented by the syntax you used: for instance, what does it mean to wrap "T" between brackets? And what does "infer U" do?

Comment: I will explain when I write up my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to approach it:

```
type NotAUnion<T> = [T] extends [infer U] ? _NotAUnion<U, U> : never;
type _NotAUnion<T, U> = U extends any ? [T] extends [U] ? unknown : never : never;

function something<T extends string & NotAUnion<T>>(): void {
    // ...
}

something<'stringOne'>(); // okay
something<'stringOne' | 'stringTwo'>(); // error
```

You can verify that it works.

---

The idea of `NotAUnion<T>` is that if `T` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), `NotAUnion<T>` should resolve to [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) (TypeScript's [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type); nothing other than `never` itself is assignable to `never`); otherwise, if `T` is *not* a union type, `NotAunion<T>` should resolve to [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) (TypeScript's [top type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type); every type is assignable to `unknown`).

The  [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T extends string & NotAUnion<T>` is a *recursive constraint*, also known as [F-bounded quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification), which is a tricky thing to get the compiler to see as acceptable.  If you're not careful you can get warnings about circular type definitions.  I *would* have worked around this in another way, but your example doesn't have any other place where `T` is used (usually it would be `doSomething<T>(t: T): void` where `T` appears as the type of a parameter or something), and so I'm keeping a version where `T extends XXX` is the only way you can express the constraint.

Anyway, `T extends string & NotAUnion<T>` expresses the idea that `T` must be assignable to `string` and must not be a union: If `T` is a union, then `string & NotAUnion<T>` will resolve to `string & never`, which resolves to `never`, and thus `T extends never` will be violated.  On the other hand, if `T` is not a union, then `string & NotAUnion<T>` will resolve to `string & unknown`, which resolves to `string`, and thus `T extends string` will be satisfied if `T` is assignable to `string`.

This gives you your desired behavior for `"stringOne"` versus `"stringOne" | "stringTwo"`.  It will also accept `string` itself, which is not a union.  If you want to prohibit this you can do so with a more complex constraint, but I'm considering that out of scope for the question as asked (since it wasn't one of the specified use cases).

---

So the only thing left to explain here is *how* `NotAUnion<T>` works.  The general idea is that `NotAUnion<T>` will check to see if `T` is assignable to all the union members of `T` individually.  If so, then `T` is not a union (since it has just one member).  If not, then `T` is a union.

The approach here is first to use [conditional type inference with `infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to copy `T` into another type parameter `U`.  By wrapping this in a single-element tuple, we are preventing this from being a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  So in `[T] extends [infer U] ? ...T,U... : never`, both `T` and `U` will be the same type.

And so `[T] extends [infer U] ? _NotAUnion<U, U> : never` is essentially the same as just `_NotAUnion<T, T>`, except that the former would make the compiler complain about circularity.  So `T extends _NotAUnion<T, T>` is seen as illegally circular, but `T extends NotAUnion<T>` is not.  Copying from `T` to `U` and then checking `U` seems to be the important piece here.

Anyway, then the `_NotAUnion<T, U>` type intentionally *distributes* the type function across union members in `U`, by writing a distributive conditional type `U extends any ? ..,T,U... : never`.  Inside that type function, `T` will be the original `T` type, while `U` will be each individual union member of `T`.  Thus is `T` is `"stringOne" | "stringTwo"`, then `U` will be `"stringOne"` and `"stringTwo"` in turn.

And finally, the real comparison: `[T] extends [U] ? unknown : never`.  This is another non-distributive type (we don't want to break `T` up into pieces).  If `T` is not a union, then this will end up being something like `"stringOne" extends "stringOne"` which will result in `unknown`.  But if `T` is a union, then this will become `("stringOne" | "stringTwo") extends "stringOne"` which is false, so you get `never`.  It also checks  `("stringOne" | "stringTwo") extends "stringTwo"`, which is equally as false.

And there you go.  It's a bit convoluted, obviously.  There are other ways to write a function like this, but they are equally or more weird.  A slightly less complex one-liner version of `NotAUnion<T>` is mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#34504](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34504) but it seems to rely on unspecified behavior that changes depending on the version of TypeScript.  Instead of hoping that the one-liner version always behaves like the two-line version I show here, I just use them more reliable two-line version here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9sAggVQHYEs6oDwBUB8UAvFANq4C6UEAHsBKgCYDOZ6qAZhAE5TJUB+KAH14SNJhzIANH0IAuKKggA3HgG4AUKEgixKDFjyzkhEsmp0GLKAENUIKEPJVa9Jq1L8nUAK6oAa1Q4AHdUKEVlNV5I1Q1NTQ5-AGNgSShmOABbCGAAC3YAczxLdxtmYG4iqAAyWAQDSTx8fAAKAEpFFTh0RigAb00oKAB6EagAOinNAF8EzJz8ouwAcgqq1EKAeWUVtvb1UfG4ANsQTQXcgs3V9aKdiBWoAB8oNcqi3BC4PY7Dseo3G4cG4F2yV2Wd02+3UQA)

Comment: "I would have worked around this in another way, but your example doesn't have any other place where T is used (usually it would be doSomething<T>(t: T): void" -- actually this is exactly my case, I wrote the function without parameters just to simplify the context. What is the most optimal way to achieve the same, knowing that T is also a parameter of the function? Maybe I can split the "T extends string & NotAUnion<T>", and move part of it to the params side?

Comment: Possibly like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NdoDdw)?   You can usually rephrase an invalid circular (`X extends F<X>`, `x: X`) pair as a valid (`X extends unknown`, `x: X & F<X>`) pair. Making a [mre] is a tricky thing because when an example is *too* minimal then it can fail to capture some relevant detail about the actual use case.